# Binding is not working for the first time in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following code in my sample.

```
 public string MyProperty
 {
     get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Hello"));

 private TestClass1 test;

 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Binding binding = new Binding
     {
         Path = new PropertyPath("MyProperty"),
         Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
     };
         test.SetValueBinding(binding);
         test.DataContext = this;
         Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
  }

  public class TestClass1 : FrameworkElement
  {
      public object Value
      {
          get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
          set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(TestClass1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

      public void SetValueBinding(Binding binding)
      {
          this.SetBinding(ValueProperty, binding);
      }
   }
```

After binding is set, if  i access test.Value, it returns null for the first time. After that,if i access it (from another method) it returns correct value "Hello".
But i do not know first time why binding is not working and null value is returned? any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't get the value for *the first time*. It's that you can't get it *so fast*. When binding is set at the time the `DataContext` is `NULL`, the source is resolved in a deferred way, perhaps later by the UI thread. You ask for value just after the binding is set, too early to get valid results.

You should switch lines in your code to:

```
test.DataContext = this;
test.SetValueBinding(binding);
```

This way the binding gets the value immediately from DataContext in the first instruction.